# Filter elements using liquid markup

Tags: liquid

Just out of curiosity is there away to filter elements using liquid markup? For example:

```
{{item.products | filter: "#selector"}}

Result: <div id="selector"></div>


{{item.products | filter: ".classSelector"}}

Results: <div id="classSelector"></div>

{{item.products | filter: "img"}}

Results: <img src="#"><img src="#"><img src="#">
```

Answer (score 0):

Liquid is a templating language. You are trying to navigate the DOM. It makes absolutely no sense to "filter" elements using CSS selectors in Liquid.

For this purpose I would recommend using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead.

However, as a followup, I would suggest that this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you **trying** to do?